# How to make special indents for a block of text

Tags: lists, indentation, block

This is what I need:

```
Headline
    First item in list
       continuation of description of first item if first line gets full
    second item on list
       continuation of description of item 2
       more continuation on item 2 if second line gets full as well
```

I need this for basically a whole chapter. How can I make this special kind of list?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There's a command called `\hangindent` (in combination with `\hangafter`) which will probably achieve what you want, but please post a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may be the solution...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe, top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item Headline
\begin{description}
  \item  First item in list\\
       continuation of description of first item if first line gets full
   \item   second item on list\\
       continuation of description of item 2
       more continuation on item 2 if second line gets full as well
\end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate the continuation indent. The continuation indent in your example is a little bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
\section*{Headline}

\noindent\hangindent3em  Bla bla bla ...

\noindent\hangindent3em  Bla bla bla ...
```

Or even

```
\section*{Headline}

{\parindent0pt
\parskip1ex
\everypar{\hangindent3em}

Bla bla bla ...\par
Bla bla bla ... \par}
```

But no dot forget the curly braces to limit the scope of the comands.